# Error while uploading a database table - Python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I'm practically new to MySQL databases. 
I am trying to make entries and I find this error in the console:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'total issues
>   (Timestamp, Count issues, Project) VALUES ('2020-04-17', '908', ''G'
>   at line 1

and this is the code I'm trying to run:

```
uploadMap = {
    'current total issues': 'apiUrl0...',
    'current total unresolved issues': 'apiUrl1...',
    'total created in the week': 'apiUrl2...',
    'total blocker created in week': 'apiUrl3...'
}

for project in ('Graphic', 'Develop'):
    for tableName, url in uploadMap.items():

        sql = f"INSERT INTO {tableName} (Timestamp, Count issues, Project) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

        val = (todaySql, getTotal(url + project), project)

        cursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Some clarifications:

- `getTotal` always returns an integer
- `todaySql` it is a date of the alleged format that MySQL would need, managed by this object:

```
class jiraDates:
    def __init__(self):
        self.format = ('%Y', '%m', '%d')

    def getJiraDate(self, daysBack):
        dateBack = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=daysBack)
        return '-'.join([dateBack.strftime(ref) for ref in self.format])

    def getSqlDate(self, daysBack):
        return datetime.strptime(self.getJiraDate(daysBack), '-'.join(self.format))

todaySql = jiraDates().getSqlDate(0)
```

I hope it is nothing serious...!

Comment: Is the table name really "current total issues"? If so, you need to wrap it in backticks "`"

Comment: @jordanm Ok I'll try! Yes, I named it on phpMyAdmin. Do you recommend putting names not separated from white spaces?

Comment: @jordanm I tried and it didn't work. Same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What [jordanm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) said is not wrong. If the names are larger than a monogram, you need to use backticks (although I highly recommend using the snake case, e.g. `name_of_the_table`). 
Another thing you need to make sure is that the date must be in this date format: `datetime.date(int(year), int(months), int(date))`. 
So you have to change these two lines:

```
def getSqlDate(self, daysBack):
    jiraDate = self.getJiraDate(daysBack).split('-')
    return datetime.date(int(jiraDate[0]), int(jiraDate[1]), int(jiraDate[2]))
```

and

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO `{tableName}` (Timestamp, `Count issues`, Project) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
```